# Having trouble importing a class

Tags: python

So im having a little trouble with this program im trying to create. 
Heres the question to the problem:
Write a class named Car that has the following data attributes:

__year_model( for the car’s year model)

__make(for the car’s make of the car)

__speed( for the car’s current speed)

The Car class should have a **init** method that accepts the car’s year model and make as arguments. It should also assign 0 to the __speed data attribute.

The class should also have the following methods:

• Accelerate The accelerate method should add 5 to the speed data attribute each time it is called.

• Brake The brake method should subtract 5 from the speed data attribute each time it is called.

• The get_speed The get_speed method should return the current speed

Next, Design a program that creates a car object, and then calls the accelerate method five times. After each call to the accelerate method, get the current speed of the car and display it. Then call the brake method five times. After each call to the brake method, get the current speed of the car and display it.

I keep getting an error ( import car
ImportError: No module named 'car') and im not sure how to fix it.

Heres my code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,year,make,speed):
    self.__year_model = year
    self.__make = make
    self.__speed = 0

    def set_year(self, year):
        self.__year = year

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.__speed = 0 

    def get_year_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -= 5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed
```

And heres the second:

```
import car

def main():

    year = input('Enter the year of the car: ')
    make = input('Enter the make of the car: ')
    speed = 0
    myCar = Car(year,make,speed)

    for num in range(5):
        myCar.accelerate()
        print('The car is accelerating... ', myCar.get_speed())

    for num in range(5):
        myCar.brake()
        print('The car is braking... ', myCar.get_speed())

main()
```

Comment: What does the directory structure look like on your file system?  What does your PYTHONPATH look like?  Are you using python2.x or python3.x?

Comment: And did you actually name the file with the `Car` class in it `car.py`? (Also, you'll need to access the class as `car.Car` after importing `car`.)

Comment: Note: instead of tradtional accessors/mutators, you should try using properties. They provide the same functionality of directly accessing members, but still allow you to do everything you would with getters/setters.

Comment: @user2357112 yes it did name it car.py

Comment: @mgilson im using 3.5

Comment: "no module named `car`" would suggest you do not have a `car.py` on the path, try putting it in the same folder as the script you are running.